# In Rust, how the Rc reference counter behaves when shadowing happens?

Tags: pointers, rust, reference

In the following code, what is the expected value of the reference counter after `drop(b)`? How to check it?

```rust
enum List {
  Cons(char, Rc<List>),
  Nil
}
  
impl Drop for List {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    match self {
      List::Cons(name, _) => println!("free {name}"),
      List::Nil => {}
    }
  }
}
  
use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
  let v = Cons('v', Rc::new(Nil));

  let a = Rc::new(&v);
  let v = Nil;
  drop(v);
  let b = Rc::clone(&a);
  println!("counter: {}", Rc::strong_count(&a));
  let a = Rc::clone(&a);
  println!("counter: {}", Rc::strong_count(&a));
  let a = Nil;
  drop(a);
  println!("counter: {}", Rc::strong_count(&b));
  drop(b);

  // is it possible to check the reference counter?

}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between the two code blocks? If there is, can you elaborate on it? If not, please remove one.

Comment: Again a question, which is not answered by the alleged duplicate. Is this AI or what is wrong with you?

Comment: @Markus AI does not close questions here, people do. In this case, I've closed this, since this case boils down to shadowing not overwrites the old variable, which is exactly why the duplicate explains. If you believe this is wrong, you can explain why and (if you have the privilege) vote to open.

Comment: I have commented to the answer below. The question was why the ref count doesn't go down. When shadowing, the compiler could throw away the ref and the ref count could go down. Why the compiler doesn't do this?

Comment: The linked answer explains that too, if perhaps somewhat less clearly. That's because access to the old variable is still possible via references.

Comment: There are no references to a. This checks the borrow checker. But you have to drop it manually to get rid of it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=042511233bb94adc601cbfbb580eb4d3

Comment: Documented language behavior does not change because there are no references. It was designed this way because of possible references, and it was designed to operate consistently.

Comment: I suppose the question can be summed up as: shouldn't an object always be dropped at the end of its lifetime? If NLL shortens an object’s lifetime to before the end of the block, shouldn't it be dropped where NLL says its lifetime ends? And the answer is no — objects are *always* dropped at the end of the block they live in regardless of the lifetime the compiler ascribes to them. **Lifetimes do not affect semantics!**

Comment: Maybe the edits I've made express my question better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there's two `a` variables and the second has shadowed the declaration of the first.  However, it doesn't *overwrite* the first one, and in fact it cannot, because they're of different types.

If you *did* want to overwrite `a`, you'd have to make the first `let a` be `let mut a` and then the second would become just `a = Cons(5, Rc::clone(&a))`, but as I mentioned, that won't compile.

The reason this behaviour is useful is that it's often necessary to create a variable to hold an intermediate value returned from a function that you want to borrow.  By allowing this kind of shadowing, you can name the intermediate value the same thing as the variable borrowing it (which can make sense in many cases), but you don't have to worry about accidentally accessing the old value, which only serves to persist the data it holds.

So you end up with 4 references to that specific `Rc` variable: the first `a`, `_b`, `c`, and the second `a`.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the compiler doesn't throw away the first shadowed a. There is no need to let it alive.